# @Autowired not working in springboot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm new to SpringBoot. The problem I am facing with `@Autowired` annotation. When I'm trying to get the autowired bean, the compiler throw `NullPointerException`.

This is the service I'm using:

```
package com.oss.mail.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.oss.mail.dao.EmailReadingDao;

@Service
public class EmailReadingService {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);


    EmailReadingDao emailReadingDao=new EmailReadingDao();

    public void readEmails(){
        logger.info("Called readEmail method from EmailReadingService");
        logger.info("Calling readEmailDao() from EmailReadingDao");
        emailReadingDao.readEmailDao();
    }
}
```

This is how I defined my DAO:

```
@Configuration
public class EmailReadingDao {
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggingHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Autowired
    private GetEmails getEmailsUtil;

  String emailHost;
    String emailPort;
    String emailUserName;
    String emailPassword;
    int NoOfEmails;

    public void readEmailDao(){

        logger.info("Called readEmailDao() from EmailReadingDao");
        Map<String, String> emailsString=new HashMap<String, String>();

        emailHost=env.getProperty("mail.pop3s.host");//Error at thir line.
        emailPort=env.getProperty("mail.pop3s.port");
        emailUserName=env.getProperty("mail.pop3s.username");
        emailPassword=env.getProperty("mail.pop3s.password");
        NoOfEmails=Integer.parseInt(env.getProperty("mail.NoOfEmails"));
```

And this is what I'm seeing in my logs:

```
2018-07-30 03:49:38 INFO  o.s.i.handler.LoggingHandler - Called readEmailDao() from EmailReadingDao
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.oss.mail.dao.EmailReadingDao.readEmailDao(EmailReadingDao.java:36)
    at com.oss.mail.service.EmailReadingService.readEmails(EmailReadingService.java:20)
    at com.oss.ProductionIncidentAutomation.ProductionIncidentAutomationApplication.main(ProductionIncidentAutomationApplication.java:32)
```

I'm not sure why the spring is not wiring this class. Please help me in getting the resolution of this.

Comment: Autowiering doesn't work if you create an object with `new` keyword. It only works in container managed beans

Answer (score 1):

Autowiring doesn't work if you create an object using the `new` keyword. It only works in container managed beans. So you have to autowire `EmailReadingDao` too.

Change:

```
EmailReadingDao emailReadingDao=new EmailReadingDao();
```

to:

```
@Autowired
EmailReadingDao emailReadingDao;
```

Also `EmailReadingDao` is not a configuration. You should annotate it with `@Repository`:

```
@Repository
public class EmailReadingDao {
```

Comment: Tried it but not working, I'm not sure why its not working. Error:Field emailReadingDao in com.oss.mail.service.EmailReadingService required a bean of type 'com.oss.mail.dao.EmailReadingDao' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.oss.mail.dao.EmailReadingDao' in your configuration.

Comment: @AbhishekSaxena Soet correctly. Check this

Answer (score 0):

Change `EmailReadingDao emailReadingDao=new EmailReadingDao();` to

```
@Autowired
private EmailReadingDao emailReadingDao;
```

or even better use constructor injection.

Then also change in your `EmailReadingDao` from `@Configuration` to `@Component`

```
@Component
public class EmailReadingDao {
...
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but not working. I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It worked when I am calling service method by creating REST API . But container fails to autowire beans when I am calling same method from autowired ref in main method of SpringBoot app. Can anyone know the reason?